# proper way to transition between PreferencesActivity and Views

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences

I have 2 UI Activities (w/ Fragments) as well as a SettingsActivity (derives from PreferenceActivity) in my first-ever android app.  It 'works' but I want to make sure I'm doing the idiomatic right thing as the user flows between views and the preferences.

Specifically - when I change my 'location' preference (when the user is in the SettingsActivity) to a different zip code, I would like the app to fetch some background data from a service.  But then I need to refresh the UI in whichever View preceded the settings change (taking the new data into account).

So is it 'the right thing to do' - to do work (fetch the background data) in the PreferenceActivity's onPreferenceChangeListener() when the zip code change, and then have the preceding UI activity consume the data (that's now updated in a singleton abstraction of the data source) in its onStart() method when the user returns to it?  Or is there a better way (e.g., to somehow capture the 'preference changed' in the UI Activities, and do all the work there, rather than in the PreferenceActivity).

Hope this isn't too abstract, I'd share code, but there's so much cleanup I'd have to do that I'm hoping this to suffice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the functionality into a seperate class `MyCurrentZipcode` that

- can be used by every activity that consumes the zip-code dependendant data and
- gets informed, if the zipcode changes.
- does the background download of the zip data.

You can create a method `MyCurrentZipcode.addOnZipcodeChanged()` where the consuming activities can register to get informed about changes.